# Deck of cards generated in PDF with Java and using iText

Tags: java, pdf

I have the next problem:

1. I've create a table in PDF, but I'm trying to find how to separate the cell with space between them, so they look a like a card.
2. I have problem with printing/showing the suits in the PDF. I got the ranks, but the suits are missing. I've try with few fonts, but there was no success.

Any ideas?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chapter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.List;
import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Section;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class DeckOf52Cards {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,IOException {

        Document generatePDF = new Document();

        FileOutputStream someName = new FileOutputStream("DeckOf52Cards.pdf");

        PdfWriter.getInstance(generatePDF, someName);

        generatePDF.open();

        BaseFont downloaded = BaseFont.createFont("Burn outfade away.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,true);

        Font[] someStyle = {
                new Font(downloaded, 40, 0, new BaseColor (0,0,0)),
                new Font(downloaded, 40, 0, new BaseColor(255,0,0))             
            };  

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);     


        String[] ranks ={"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};
        char[] suits = {'\u2660','\u2663','\u2666','\u2665'};


        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {

                if (suits[j] == '\u2666' || suits[j] == '\u2665') {
                    table.addCell(new Paragraph(suits[j] + ranks[i] + "",someStyle[0]));
                }
                else {
                    table.addCell(new Paragraph(ranks[i] + suits[j] + "",someStyle[1]));
                }
            }
        }       
        generatePDF.add(table);
        generatePDF.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a font that contains these characters? (Most fonts do not.)

Comment: First try was with the most common font - arial, but the same moment - nothing appears.

Comment: I've lied. After restart they appear - with arial. That's fine thanks. But I'm still looking for info how can I do a space/ to separate/ the cells in this table. I'll be greatfull for help.